# Screen support for different screen size

Tags: android, android-layout

In my application i have layouts as given below

```
layout/example.xml
layout-land/example.xml

layout-small/example.xml
layout-small-land/example.xml

layout-large/example.xml
layout-large-land/example.xml

layout-xlarge/example.xml
layout-xlarge-land/example.xml
```

i tested my app with HTC sensation and LG optimus Net P699 (320x480). For HTC sensation it is taking the layout from  
    `layout-large/example.xml
    layout-large-land/example.xml`
 But for P699 it is taking the layout from `layout/example.xml` for both landscape and portrait mode. Why it is so ??? For landscape it must have from `layout-land/example.xml` right ??

Comment: so its not supporting your screen

Comment: Yea..For LG P699 the layout is taking from layout/example.xml

Comment: Did you try the normal screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Layouts are picked by suitability of the device even if you specify them for size or density.

As android layout's range have overlapping boundaries so on many occasions it tends to confuse them. 
Simply add **another folder for portrait mode layouts and further categories them**.

Remove `layout/example.xml` and make it `layout-port/example.xml`